# Error when trying to use MirroredStrategy in tf.estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to add multi-gpu support to my tensorflow training code using tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy as a parameter to tf.estimator.RunConfig.

Tensorflow version: 1.7 (compiled from source)

Python version: 3.5

OS Platform and version: Linux Ubuntu 16.04.2

I get the following error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 297, in stop_on_exception
    yield
  File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/mirrored_strategy.py", line 248, in _call_for_each_tower
    self, *merge_args, **merge_kwargs)
  File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 667, in _distributed_apply
    reduced_grads = distribution.batch_reduce("sum", grads_and_vars)
  File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/distribute.py", line 801, in batch_reduce
    return self._batch_reduce(method_string, value_destination_pairs)
  File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/mirrored_strategy.py", line 295, in _batch_reduce
    value_destination_pairs)
  File "python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distribute/python/cross_tower_ops.py", line 169, in batch_reduce
    raise ValueError("`value_destination_pairs` must be a list or a tuple of "
ValueError: `value_destination_pairs` must be a list or a tuple of tuples of PerDevice objects and destinations
```

The following code produces the error (I omitted the code for parsing the tfrecord to image tensor as I don't believe this code effects the error, but I can add it if necessary):

```py
import glob, os
import tensorflow as tf
slim = tf.contrib.slim

# ...
# definition of args (arguments parser)

def input_fn():

    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(glob.glob(os.path.join(args.train_data_dir, 'train*')))
    dataset = dataset.map(
                lambda x: parse_and_preprocess_image(x, args.image_size),
                num_parallel_calls=2,
    )
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=4)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

    return dataset


def model_fn(features, labels=None, mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, params=None):

    train_images_batch = features
    res = slim.conv2d(inputs=train_images_batch, kernel_size=9, stride=1, num_outputs=3, scope='conv1')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean((train_images_batch - res) ** 2)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)
    train_op = slim.learning.create_train_op(loss, optimizer)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN,
        loss=loss, train_op=train_op)


def train():

    init()

    distribution = tf.contrib.distribute.MirroredStrategy(num_gpus=args.num_gpus)

    config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
        model_dir=args.log_dir,
        train_distribute=distribution,
    )

    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, config=config)
    estimator.train(
            input_fn=input_fn,
            max_steps=args.train_steps,
        )


def main():
    add_arguments()
    train()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you!

Adva

Answer (score 1):

This error happens if you specified `num_gpus=1`. For a single GPU, you can use `OneDeviceStrategy("/device:GPU:0")` instead of `MirroredStrategy`.